# Generate Multiple Matches of partial match

Tags: excel, multidimensional-array, indexing, excel-formula

I created an array function, and my aim is to look through the elements of column H and compare them with elements of column D. If H partially matches D (i.e. H&"*" to D), i want the elements in column E reported for all partial matches.
I use the below code, and it works fine, except i cant wrap my head around how to make H match elements of D even if H is only a partial match (with D having more characters to its right).

Thank you all for the anticipated assistance.

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($E$2:$E$1526, SMALL(IF($H2=$D$2:$D$1526, ROW($E$2:$E$1526)-1,""),COLUMN()-9)),"")}
```

Comment: Your formula do not partial match `IF($H2=$D$2:$D$1526....`. Show some example data with expected result. I think this can be achieved without array formula.

Answer (score 0):

Try using helper cells for this

This goes into your first column of helper cells. It will provide a 1 or a 0 for each entry you have.
G1 is the look up value and A2:A108 is the table/list to search against
`=--ISNUMBER(IFEEROR(SEARCH($G$1,$A$2:$A$108,1),""))`

In the next column put this formula
`=If(D2=1,COUNTIF($D$2:D2,1),"")`
Column D2 is the results of the first equation.

Lastly in another column put this
`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$108,MATCH(ROWS($E$2:E2),$E$2:$E$108,0)),"")`
Where E2 to E108 is the result of the countif formula.

[Here is an example of the above formulas in action.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nTLYQwP9W9NccklWhEHEW7dA7tZLSpMv/view?usp=sharing)